# MariaDB - Index not used when there is datatype mismatch between columns in join even after cast

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to join two tables where there is a datatype mismatch between the join columns. Index is not getting picked up even after an explicit conversion (or after forcing the index). What could be the reason?

```
create table table_a (
    table_a_col1 decimal(18) 
); 

create table table_b (
    rec_id decimal(18) ,
    table_b_col2 varchar(18)
);

create index table_b_col2_ndx on table_b (table_b_col2);

insert into table_a values (1);
insert into table_a values (2);

insert into table_b values (1,'1');
insert into table_b values (2,'2');
insert into table_b values (4,'S');

commit;
```

Plan without doing any conversion

```
explain
select  *
from table_a
left join table_b 
on  (table_b_col2 = table_a_col1)
where table_a_col1 = 2;

|id |select_type|table  |type|possible_keys   |key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra                                         |
|---|-----------|-------|----|----------------|---|-------|---|----|----------------------------------------------|
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_a|ALL |                |   |       |   |2   |Using where                                   |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_b|ALL |table_b_col2_ndx|   |       |   |3   |Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)|
```

Plan after explicit datatype conversion

```
explain
select  *
from table_a
left join table_b 
on  (table_b_col2 = cast(table_a_col1 as character))
where table_a_col1 = 2;

|id |select_type|table  |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra                                          |
|---|-----------|-------|----|-------------|---|-------|---|----|-----------------------------------------------|
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_a|ALL |             |   |       |   |2   |Using where                                    |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_b|ALL |             |   |       |   |3   |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
```

Plan after forcing the index

```
explain
select  *
from table_a
left join table_b force index (table_b_col2_ndx)
on  (table_b_col2 = cast(table_a_col1 as character))
where table_a_col1 = 2;

|id |select_type|table  |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra                                          |
|---|-----------|-------|----|-------------|---|-------|---|----|-----------------------------------------------|
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_a|ALL |             |   |       |   |2   |Using where                                    |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table_b|ALL |             |   |       |   |3   |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|


select version() ;

|version()         |
|------------------|
|10.2.9-MariaDB-log|
```

Comment: You can't use an index if you compute that column. There is way around that. Indexes can only be used on the raw column data and not on the manipulated data.

Comment: @juergend table_b_col2 is not a computed column. Index is available on this column

Comment: You cast in the join condition. That can't use indexes

Comment: cast is used on the column of table_a, index which is not used is actually from table_b

Comment: That does not matter. You cast in the join condition.

Comment: What could be the solution for these kind of problems? Use of function index would help?